# Is it possible to get data from SD card with SPI on my computer?

Tags: spi

I need to try to find ways to corrupt/change some data in a SD card, but the  thing is, the SD card is in microcontroller, so it works with SPI. What I would like to do in a perfect world is to clone this card and then play with the cloned card. So is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you could try the arduino interface to read/write data from/to SD card via SPI.. there are many tutorial on the internet about accessing SD card data via arduino

Comment: the thing is, i would like to reads/write data without spi. I want to just insert it in my pc and read in some way. But thanks anyway

Comment: I dont understand very clearly, if the sd card is really sd card, it must work with card reader and pc.. card reader works also with spi.. if the sd card doesnt look like obvious sd card, how you know, it s SD card? if you definitely know, that card works with microcontroller via spi communication, try to make some kind of usb to spi converter (or look at aliexpress), and via some Terminal SW in the PC, you would access that.. BTW : if access to card is given by spi communication, there is no way to access card data without spi